# Reverting to a git branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit, and I want to go back to the end of a branch last committed three days ago. I've hard reset a couple of times but since I'm unfamiliar with git I risk doing something foolish and would appreciate help.

Looking at the image here:

[image]

'`master`' is currently set at the version made at 17:40:56 on 10 Jan. This is where I'd like the latest version to be both locally and remotely. (Some text redacted in this image).

However, I see that `origin/HEAD` and `origin/master` are at the version made at 11:04:01 on 13 Jan (today).

So for clarity, I want to revert to the end of the green branch, and make that version the master version. What must I do to get there?

Please say if I need to provide more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to right click on that commit referenced by master, select push, and select the "`force`" option in order to `push --force` your master onto the remote.
("`Force Overwrite Existing Branch (May discard changes)`")

Make sure to communicate that to other using that same remote repo, because you would be changing an history that others might already have pulled from.

[image: http://joelabrahamsson.com/PageFiles/215/1664_1998.jpg]

Comment: Thanks to you VonC and Bhaskar for your answers (and to VonC for formatting the question properly). I did as VonC suggested, which in principle worked - as it happened, another user had an older version stored and we decided to revert to that. Sorry, I'm unable to dish out points, having a low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I have partial answer to your question. I don't know `tortoisegit` so what are the black and red lines in the graph? I imagine the green is `master` branch. Is this image for local repo? What is your current branch name?

Using git on commandline/terminal window you can do following.

You can move `HEAD` to any commit. For brevity, lets say the `SHA of Jan 10th 17:40:56` commit is `c`. If this is your commit history/log.

```
a----b----c----d----e <-- master branch 
                    ^
                    HEAD
```

So, doing `git checkout c` should set the `HEAD` where you want leaving the later commits in place.

```
a----b----c----d----e <-- master branch 
          ^
          HEAD
```

This is called `detached` state. If you do `git branch`, it says so. You can continue to do new commits from this point, but since they are not referenced by any branch, git can garbage collect them.

Alternately, if you want to delete commits `d` and `e` and move `HEAD` to `c`, do `git reset --hard c`. If you want to leave `d` and `e` changes in there but move `HEAD` and `master` branch to `c`, do `git reset --soft c`. You'll see the `d` and `e` as changes to be committed in `git status`.